# How to consume a Service in Nest.js middleware

Tags: nestjs

I need to use `HttpService` from `@nestjs/axios` in some middleware to verify captcha responses.

I have registered the middleware in `app.module.ts` like this:

```js
@Module({
  // ...
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, HttpService] <---- added HttpService here
})

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(CaptchaMiddleware)
      .forRoutes(
        { path: '/users', method: RequestMethod.POST }
      );
  }
}
```

This is what `captcha.middleware.ts` looks like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CaptchaMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    constructor(
        private readonly httpService: HttpService
    ) { }

    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        // ... code to verify captcha ...
      
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN */ ]
  })
```

What is the correct way to add `HttpService` as a dependency of `CaptchaMiddleware`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be importing the `HttpModule`, not providing the `HttpService`. [Just like it's described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module). When you provide a provider, Nest tries to make an instance of that provider, when you import the module, Nest will re-use the provider if it exists or create a new one with the module's provider definition.